# WebLogic 12c JAX-RS and JSON marshalling

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm trying to deploy REST web service on WebLogic 12c. I followed [the official](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/use-jersey20-ri.htm#RESTF290) guide to configure the Jersey runtime and deploy the service.

Everything seems to work, until I return any object from the REST method. Here is the snippet

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Foo> getFoos() {
    return repo.getFoos();
}
```

The method returns "Internal server error" string as a payload. Oddly enough, I don't see any runtime exceptions in the server log. Same applies to any object type. However, I can return String with according media type with no problem.

Seems like there is some problem with the JSON marshalling. Do I need further configuration to enable the JSON marshaller?

Comment: [Use an ExceptionMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31289875/2587435) to catch possibly swallowed exceptions,

Comment: @Paul Samsotha This helped. The problem was cyclic object graph, which was solved by `@XmlInverseReference`.