# Jersey web service not handling XML, but JSON

Tags: java, rest, maven, jaxb, jersey

I'm currently working on a Jersey/Hibernate web service (in Tomcat 9 container) which should be able to consume and produce JSON (application/json) and XML (application/xml) as well. It supports GET and POST to consume those types. DELETE is supported and works, as well as GET and POST for JSON. But as soon as I try the same with XML content type, I get a 500 Internal server error.

The structure is as following: (Check code below)
A songlist (Songlist class) has a list of songs and an owner (User class).

You can get a song under /(myWSname)/songs/{id} in XML and post one as well without any trouble.

I assume that the problem here are the XML annotations, because for JSON everything works like it is now. I tried to add @XmlElement and @AccessorType(FIELD). None of this helped. Furthermore, everything works well for songs under /(myWSname)/songs/{id}.

````
    @Entity
    @Table(name="songlists")
    @XmlRootElement(name = "songList")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Songlist {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty(value = "id")
    @XmlElement
    private int id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonProperty("owner")
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    @XmlElement
    private User owner = null;

    @JsonProperty("isPrivate")
    @XmlElement
    private boolean isPrivate;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "songlists_songs", joinColumns = {    @JoinColumn(name = "list_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "song_id") })
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "songs")
    @XmlElement(name = "song")
    @JsonProperty(value = "songs")
    private List<Song> songs = null;


    //JAXB no arg constructor 
    public Songlist() {
    }

    // Here: other constructors
    // and Getters and Setters for all fields 


    }```
````

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "song")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Table(name="songs")
public class Song {

@Id
@Column(name="song_id")
@JsonProperty("id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@XmlAttribute (name = "id")
private Integer id;

@NotNull
@JsonProperty("title")
@XmlAttribute (name = "title")
private String title;

@JsonProperty("artist")
@XmlAttribute (name = "artist")
private String artist;


@JsonProperty("album")
@XmlAttribute (name = "album")
private String album;


@JsonProperty("released")
@XmlAttribute (name = "released")
private Integer released;

@JsonIgnore
@XmlTransient
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="songs")
private List<Songlist> songlists;

//JAXB no arg constructor
public Song() {
}

// here: some other constructors
// and Getters and Setters for all fields
```

}```

Unfortunately, there are no log messages for this. From my research I did, apparently this is an JAXB issue.

Comment: [Register a generic ExeptionMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31289875/2587435). You will probably get a stack trace giving you the reason for the error.

Comment: '*should be able to consume and produce JSON (application/json) and XML (application/xml) as well.*' Are you sure? Check the `@Consumes` annotations on the JAX-RS class and its methods.

Comment: I did not express it correctly. GET should @produce XML and JSON, POST should consume both content types. I checked the annotations, they are in place. I implemented an ExceptionMapper which helped for one part - the exception was that a writer for ```application/xml``` is missing. I added the JAX-RS media dependency and introduced a ```GenericType``` which works well. Thank you.

Comment: @vickylaram could you please elaborate in details as I am also having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to make the songfest field in the User class (which I didn't post, because I didn't expect this to be the error source) XML transient as this would reference the songlist and the songlist would reference the user. Endless cycle apparently.